# Post and Reconcile buttons in versionig toolbar grayed out in Arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, postgresql, versioning, reconcile

I have a versioned GDB (Postgresql) and I have versions DEFAULT-> A -> B.
Version A modifies two poly lines and version B modifies one of the two that is modified in version A.
In ArcMap, even though I have "List by source" selected and have selected the source (which also shows the selected version), I do not get "Post" nor "Reconcile" buttons enabled in the versioning toolbar when either version A or B is selected. Am I missing something or this is a bug?

For reference, I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3 with all patches installed as of now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to start editing in order for the versioning buttons to be available. Go to Editor toolbar and "Start Editing". When you are finished with Reconcile and Post, Save and Stop Editing.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that if you use the reconcile versions tool from the data management tool box, you can reconcile versions without being in an edit session.  You can just drag your database connection in to the Input DB connection.  Perhaps that may be an alternative solutions to what you are looking for?